# Openshift: Automatically update upstream images

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

In Openshift we have a BuildConfig which depends on an image from hub.docker.com (`ubuntu:xenial`).

```
strategy:
  type: Docker
  dockerStrategy:
    from:
      kind: ImageStreamTag
      namespace: <my namespace>
      name: 'ubuntu:xenial'
    forcePull: true
```

For this I created an ImageStream with the following config:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ImageStream
metadata:
  name: ubuntu
  namespace: <my namespace>
spec:
  dockerImageRepository: registry.hub.docker.com/library/ubuntu
```

I now would like to run my BuildConfig whenever the upstream Ubuntu image changes. I can update the Ubuntu image manually by running `oc import-image ubuntu`.

Is there another way to automatically update the image other than create an external cron job?

*Versions*

```
OpenShift Master: v1.3.1
Kubernetes Master: v1.3.0+52492b4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at `scheduled` field of the `importPolicy` associated with the image stream tag.

```
$ oc explain is.spec.tags.importPolicy
RESOURCE: importPolicy <Object>

DESCRIPTION:
     Import is information that controls how images may be imported by the
     server.

    TagImportPolicy describes the tag import policy

FIELDS:
   insecure <boolean>
     Insecure is true if the server may bypass certificate verification or
     connect directly over HTTP during image import.

   scheduled    <boolean>
     Scheduled indicates to the server that this tag should be periodically
     checked to ensure it is up to date, and imported
```

There is a mention of it in:

- [Importing Tag and Image Metadata](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.3/dev_guide/managing_images.html#importing-tag-and-image-metadata)

Comment: `oc tag ... --scheduled` Will set that for you

Comment: What is the time set for ```scheduled``` param to look periodically for new image/imageTag?

Comment: @Poli Default is every 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in documentation:

"Querying external registries to synchronize tag and image metadata is not currently an automated process. To resynchronize manually, run oc import-image . Within a short amount of time, OpenShift will communicate with the external registry to get up to date information about the Docker image repository associated with the image stream"

https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/architecture/infrastructure_components/image_registry.html#third-party-registries

You can always take advantage of DockerHub Webhooks (they are triggered when an image is built in, or a new tag added):

https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/webhooks/

Comment: You are referring to documentation for an older version of OpenShift. Check https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.3/dev_guide/managing_images.html#importing-tag-and-image-metadata for a mention of updating details of images.